# Fetch a ID values from a URL

Tags: javascript, titanium

So I have a url, say

I am using it with the Titanium Appcelerator, So I am wondering whether these jquery code will work with Titanium.

```
url = 'abc.com/ab/a.aspx?b_no=0a1'
```

The html for the url is

```
    <form method="post" action="a.aspx?b_no=0a1" id="form2">

 <span id="SPAN" style="font-size:medium">[{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"},{"d":"4"}]</span>
  </form>
```

So I want to fetch that SPAN value from the url.. 
Might be a noobish question/formation of the question.. But learning bits and tricks..
Please guide..

Comment: So you want to scrape that URL with clientside javascript? Is it on the same domain? Javascript in a browser enviroment has a same-origin policy.

Comment: It is not the same domain.. I just put up an example for people to understand...

When I am using this 
`var SPAN = document.getElementById("lblbatch");`  with the html source code I am able to generate the required thing.. But I want to get that information from the url..

I

Comment: What do u mean by span value do u need this [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"},{"d":"4"}]

Comment: Then you probably can't, generally scraping is done on the serverside, as clientside javascript don't have access.

Comment: Yes sushil, I need that part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [jquery load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can do it like this:

[Solution](http://jsbin.com/tewut/2/edit?js,output)

[Url for solution](http://jsbin.com/cajan/2/edit)

```
var url = 'abc.com/ab/a.aspx?b_no=0a1';

$.get( url, function( data ) {
  var span = $( "#SPAN", data );
  var array = JSON.parse( span.text() );
  alert( array[0].a ); //1
});
```

Comment: did you inserted the jquery link?

Comment: You mean this right?

`
 var url = 'abc.com/ab/a.aspx?b_no=0a1';
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
$.get( url, function( data ) {
  var span = $( "#SPAN", data );
  var array = JSON.parse( span.text() );
  alert( array[0].a ); //1
}); 
`

Not able to format the code in the comment, Please excuse..

Comment: no you gotta add this "<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>" to your html file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need.

```
var url = "abc.com/ab/a.aspx?b_no=0a1";

$.get( url, function(data) {
  var span=$(data).find("#SPAN"); // selecting span from html
  var result=span.text(); // text of the span
});
```

Check this fiddle http://jsbin.com/dejocihu/1/edit

Comment: Are you making call to same site or its a cross site call?

Comment: The url is just an example url.. I cannot share that exact url for some privacy/security reason..

Comment: My doubt is its same origin/domain call or you are calling other domain. If its some other domain then need to make xss call.

Comment: It is probably same origin
Not getting your point exactly, but there's no need of any xss call..
abc.com/ab/a.aspx?b_no=0a1

This is just a sample url, the code behind the url has an ID called SPAN which contains those values which I want to fetch from the URL and not the HTML

Hope I understood you point well

Comment: Not working for my url, :|
I need that array part.. I will try to frame the question better way, once I am home, Thanks for helping out or rather trying out. :)